# Probleme of recognizing image in pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

i'm making an autodrafter for league of legend.
My programm has to auto accept games, I'm using the locateImage function. I've taken screens from the league accept button.
The problem is that my code doesn't works when the accept button popup but my code works when I't works when I display my image model.
Here is the recognitzion code

```
 button_pos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('accept_game.png',confidence=0.7)
        if button_pos != None:
            print("button_appeared ")
            return True
        else:
            print("image not found")
        return False
```

I've tried to it with multiples screenshots and multiple confidence values

Comment: first you could use `pyautogui` to take screenshot to see what it can really get. Maybe it doesn't have access to game screen - because games may use non-standard method to display it.

Comment: No, pyautogui access to the lol window. I've tried to run the programm with my league icon to detect and the programm worked

Comment: so maybe your image `accept_game` is too different then object on screen - ie it may have different background. You may have to check with smaller `confidence`. OR maybe you have to crop it and search only some part of element - without background which can be different. Frankly, without seeing images we have no idea what can be the problem. Besides I don't have this game and I could not test it.